# Want to enable button when checkbox is checked and also it is enabled

Tags: jquery, html, button, checkbox, scroll

I just want to enable the button when check box is `checked` and `enabled`, but its not working so, it is also depending on the above `textarea` scroll. After checking the `check box` it needs to scroll up and down to enable the button.
here is my html:

```
<textarea rows="20">
  The Fédération Internationale de Football Association (FIFA, /ˈfiːfə/; English: Federation of International Football Associations) is the international governing body of association football, futsal and beach soccer. Its membership comprises 209 national associations. Its headquarters are in Zurich, Switzerland, and its president is Sepp Blatter. FIFA is responsible for the organisation of football's major international tournaments, notably the World Cup. The need for a single body to oversee association football became apparent at the beginning of the 20th century with the increasing popularity of international fixtures. FIFA was founded in Paris on 21 May 1904; the French name and acronym persist even outside French-speaking countries. The founding members were the national associations of Belgium, Denmark, France, the Netherlands, Spain (represented by Madrid Football Club; the Spanish federation was not created until 1913), Sweden and Switzerland. Also, that same day, the German Association declared its intention of affiliating through a telegram.
</textarea>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" value="I agree all." id="agre"/>I agree all.
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

and here is jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("textarea").scroll(function(){
    var scrol=$("textarea").scrollTop();

    if (scrol == '373'){
      $("#agre").removeAttr('disabled');

    }
    else
    {
      $("#agre").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    var stat;
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
      stat=$(this).prop('checked');
    });
    var disabl=$(":checkbox").prop('disabled');
    if($(":checkbox").prop('checked') == true && disabl != true){
      $(":submit").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
      $(":submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please du not use `attr` and `removeAddr` for the `disabled` property. Use `.prop('disabled', true_or_false)` instead. Same applies for `checked` where you area already doing the right thing.

Comment: Use `if (scrol > 373)` instead of `if (scrol == '373')`

Comment: I have changed the remvAttr with prop, however    if(scrol>373) didn't work. And also i don't have any issue with scroll, it is working fine... I want to enable submit button when checkbox is enabeld and also checked.

Comment: Solvd the issue thanks Roger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (you don't need the `else` as maybe the user scrolls back up when he is done reading):

```
if (scrol > 370) {
  $('#agre').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Then, outside if the textarea scroll listener:

```
$('#agre').change(function() {
  $(':submit').attr('disabled', !$('#agre').is(':checked'));
});
```

This is also much shorter and does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

you are defining your change() handler within the scroll event handler. Try taking it out inside the `document.ready()`

Comment: I have tried but by doing this the submit button remain disabled...
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").scroll(function(){
  var scrol=$("textarea").scrollTop();
  
  if (scrol == '373'){
   $("#agre").removeAttr('disabled');
   
  }
  else
  {
   $("#agre").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
 });
 var stat;
 $(":checkbox").change(function(){
  stat=$(this).prop('checked');
 });
 var disabl=$(":checkbox").prop('disabled');
 if(stat == true && disabl != true){
  $(":submit").removeAttr('disabled');
 }
 else
 {
  $(":submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
 }
 
    });

Comment: I have also tried taking the change function out of the document.ready but still submit button remains disabled.

Comment: change function is working properly, i have tired it using alert but the button remains disabled

Comment: Please let everyone know how you did it. If any of the provided answeres worked, please mark them as answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this

**HTML**

```
   <textarea rows="20" id="txtarea">The Fédération Internationale de Football Association (FIFA, /ˈfiːfə/; English: Federation of International Football Associations) is the international governing body of association football, futsal and beach soccer. Its membership comprises 209 national associations. Its headquarters are in Zurich, Switzerland, and its president is Sepp Blatter. FIFA is responsible for the organisation of football's major international tournaments, notably the World Cup. The need for a single body to oversee association football became apparent at the beginning of the 20th century with the increasing popularity of international fixtures. FIFA was founded in Paris on 21 May 1904; the French name and acronym persist even outside French-speaking countries. The founding members were the national associations of Belgium, Denmark, France, the Netherlands, Spain (represented by Madrid Football Club; the Spanish federation was not created until 1913), Sweden and Switzerland. Also, that same day, the German Association declared its intention of affiliating through a telegram.</textarea>
<div><input type="checkbox"  value="I agree all." id="agre"/>I agree all.</div>
<div><input type="submit" id="txt"  value="Submit" /></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#agre").attr('disabled',true);
 $("#txt").attr('disabled',true);
$("textarea").scroll(function(){

   var scrol=$("textarea").scrollTop();

        if (scrol >= '373'){
            $("#agre").prop('disabled',false);

        }
        else
        {
            $("#agre").attr('disabled',true);
        }
  });
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
           {
                $("#txt").attr('disabled',false);
           }
    else
    {
         $("#txt").attr('disabled',true);
    }
        });
```

**[JSFIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/h5gGZ/1/)**